# How to send email with webintent plugin - Monaca IDE

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, onsen-ui, monaca

Somebody kindly guide me for sending email through webintent plugin for Monaca

Answer (score 1):

send an email using the "template_a" template

```
var username = 'John';
monaca.cloud.Mailer.sendMail("userOidA", "template_a", {"name": username})
  .done
  (
    function()
    { /* What to do after sending an email is success. */ }
  );
```

Comment: hang on..!!!
should i change my question because i think webintent serves the purpose- will let the user pick the app through which email can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

After my frustration fueled-up my curiosity i have some `function test () {
                window.plugins.webintent.startActivity (
                    {
                        action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        url: 'mailto:someone@example.com'
                    },
                    function () {},
                    function () {alert ('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');}
                );
            }`

Comment: you need to fire function "test".